# How to enable access control with SSH access to Bitbucket?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have a requirement where i need to enable SSH access to various repositories in Bitbucket. I want to also grant access on a need basis to the developers. Earlier I was using HTTPS so it was not a problem - I would create groups and add users to those groups. The access would be controlled by the group.

Now I have to move to SSH based repo links for the developers. To test the access control, I added my SSH key in the company workspace and it granted me access to all the repos of the company. How can I enforce access control with SSH via the groups method used earlier ? Or will I have to stick with HTTPS ?

Answer (score 1):

When you're using SSH access for a Git repository, the way the server knows who you are is by what SSH key you use.  In your case, you're using *your* SSH key, which is associated with an account that has full administrative access, so you are capable of accessing all the repositories.

The same groups you were using before should work just fine, because when your developers access the repositories, they'll be accessing using their SSH keys, which the server will recognize as belonging to their accounts, and they'll be restricted to what they can access by their normal groups.

Each developer can create their own SSH key on their machine as normal and upload it to the server using the web interface and they'll be able to access only the things they should have access to.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Another quick one if you can help - what do you prefer - HTTPS or SSH to access git ?

Comment: I slightly prefer SSH, since  tends to be more secure because it doesn't rely on a shared secret (a password), but HTTPS is also fine if you use a token.